# How to enable an Intellij plugin copied to the plugins directory

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins

I have unzipped the `ScalaToKotlin` plugin to the `intellij plugins` directory:

```
$pwd
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins


09:32:26/plugins $find  IntellijScalaToKotlin/
IntellijScalaToKotlin/
IntellijScalaToKotlin/lib
IntellijScalaToKotlin/lib/intellijScalaToKotlin-0.1.1.jar
```

How do I enable this in the IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the correct directory, please use `idea.plugins.path` instead, see [the documentation](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) for the location of this directory on your system.

The better way would be to use the **Install Plugin from Disk...**:

[image: Install Plugin from Disk...]

Then point to the `.zip` file.

Make sure the plug-in you are installing is compatible with your IntelliJ IDEA build.

Comment: Thanks I was not familiar with the  `Install plugin from disk`.

Answer (score 0):

Following on to the accepted answer from *The Source* ( @CrazyCoder is the head of QA @JetBrains)  the following info is provided when using the recommended approach of `Install Plugin from Disk`

[image]

So it is helpful to get this clear indication of the plugin being obsolete / no longer supported.